# Width returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following structure in place

```
<div class="row">
<div class="xs-col-12">
<my-custom-element id="elemId"></my-custom-element>
</div>
</div>
```

The following jQuery call to get width of my custom element (it is a angular directive) returns value of 300.

```
var width = $("#elemId").width();
```

I was expecting that this value will be full width of available width in the browser area. This is returned correctly as 1069 in IE. But in chrome it always returns 300. After debugging inside jQuery, I found that it is returning  value of offsetWidth on that element.

What am I missing here? Why I am not getting correct value in Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: can you setup a fiddle demonstrating this?

Comment: Do you mean the element is wider than 300px, but it says it's 300? Or that the element is 300px wide, and it should be more?

Comment: how about `outerWidth()`?

Comment: Oriol, your comment just made me think that I was looking for something that is not even there. This custom element was just contained in outer DIV. The intent was to calculate the width of container at run time and then set width of this custom element based on some other algorithm using container width as base. I have changed the code to use $("#elemId").parent().width().

Answer (score 0):

try outer width it includes also padding:

```
var width = $("#elemId").outerWidth();
```

or to include also margin:

```
var width = $("#elemId").outerWidth(true);
```